# Counting totals on two separate SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two (identical for this purpose) tables

#### ToDoList

```
ItemBatch | Item
   abc       Pickup sticks
   abc       Tie my shoe
   xyz       Suck my thumb
   abc       Climb a tree
```

#### DoneList

```
ItemBatch | Item
   abc      Tie my shoe
```

I'm trying to get a count from each of these per [ItemBatch] but not sure if that's actually possible in one query?

Separately I'd just do

```
select count(*) from ToDoList where ItemBatch = 'abc' /* repeat for each ItemBatch */

select count(*) from DoneList where ItemBatch = 'abc' /* repeat for each ItemBatch */
```

and assign to variables in the front-end so I could get the following:

```
ItemBatch | Total | DoneList | DoneList - ToDoList
   abc       3        1           2
   xyz       1        0           1
```

Is there a query that can give me that entire output in one fell swoop? I tried joining for starters

```
select count(cc.[ItemBatch]), count(cq.[ItemBatch])
from ToDoList cc
left join DoneList cq on cc.[ItemBatch] = cq.[ItemBatch]
```

Quickly realised that's not going to work...

Then I thought about

```
select
(select count(*) from ToDoList where [ItemBatch] = 'abc' ) as Total,
(select count(*) from DoneList where [ItemBatch] = 'abc' ) as DoneList
```

but I can't figure out how to get all rows outputted for each `ItemBatch` in one go, `group by` doesn't work for that last statement:

```
select
    (select [ItemBatch], count([ItemBatch]) from ToDoList group by [ItemBatch) as Total,
    (select [ItemBatch], count([ItemBatch]) from DoneList group by [ItemBatch]) as DoneList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `OUTER APPLY` in your case because of the calculation in the `SELECT` statement.

> The OUTER APPLY operator returns all the rows from the left table
> expression irrespective of its match with the right table expression.
> For those rows for which there are no corresponding matches in the
> right table expression, it contains NULL values in columns of the
> right table expression.

So, your statement should be:

```sql
SELECT 
        cc.ItemBatch, 
        COUNT(*) as Total,
        ISNULL(dl.DoneListTotal, 0) as DoneList,
        COUNT(*) - ISNULL(dl.DoneListTotal, 0) as [DoneList - ToDoList]
FROM ToDoList cc
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) DoneListTotal
                  FROM DoneList cq
                  WHERE cc.ItemBatch = cq.ItemBatch) dl
GROUP BY cc.ItemBatch, dl.DoneListTotal;
```

Comment: I had to add a comma and `dl.DoneListTotal` as part of the `GROUP BY` but otherwise this worked perfectly, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `LEFT JOIN` method will work if you use the right `JOIN` conditions:

```
select count(cc.[ItemBatch]), count(cq.[ItemBatch])
from ToDoList cc left join
     DoneList cq
     on cc.[ItemBatch] = cq.[ItemBatch] AND cc.Item = cq.Item;
```

Per `ItemBatch` you would add a `GROUP BY`:

```
select ItemBatch, count(*), count(cq.ItemBatch)
from ToDoList cc left join
     DoneList cq
     on cc.ItemBatch = cq.ItemBatch AND cc.Item = cq.Item
group by cc.ItemBatch
```

Comment: _"... left join ... right join conditions:"_  here is a good case for not using "right" as a synonym for correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` to get all the `ItemBatch`es of the 2 tables, with 2 additional columns `ToDo` and `Done` to indicate whch table they belong to and aggregate:

```
SELECT ItemBatch,
       SUM(Todo) ToDo,
       SUM(Done) Done,
       SUM(Todo) - SUM(Done) Difference
FROM (
  SELECT ItemBatch, 1 ToDo, 0 Done FROM ToDoList
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ItemBatch, 0, 1 FROM DoneList 
) t
GROUP BY ItemBatch
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33b266db59675065d4587512083ecc30).
Results:

```
> ItemBatch | ToDo | Done | Difference
> :-------- | ---: | ---: | ---------:
> abc       |    3 |    1 |          2
> xyz       |    1 |    0 |          1
```